# The procedure entry point ssl_ctx_set_ciphersuites could not be located in the dynamic link library libmysql.dll

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I followed the MYSQL documentation how to download it and use it with Visual Studio 2019. I have included all the files and folders into the linker and compiler etc. after installing MYSQL from its installer `MYSQL Connector C++ 8.0` & `MYSQL Server 8.0`. And I made sure that I had my build on Release x64. I got an error afterwards after executing my console application stating that `libmysql.dll` was not found. So i got it from the `MYSQL Connector C++ 8.0` Folder and threw it into the `Release > x64` Of my project directory. Then got a completely new error as shown below:

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szlfP.png)

Comment: Probably means you have an incompatible `libmysql.dll` that windows found when looking for this dll. What I mean by this it does not match the one you linked against.  Perhaps there is a different `libmysql.dll` in your folders.

Comment: ***So i got it from the MYSQL Connector C++ 8.0 Folder and threw it into the Release > x64 Of my project directory.*** Windows found this dll in the OS system32 folder which is incompatible with the one you linked to.

Comment: Yeah i figured that out, I used a 32BIT Architecture libmysql rather than a 64BIT